# Jquery in Cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp

how do we use jquery in php?

I am using an external javascript file and i mentioned that in the default.ctp file.. It is working on my localhost but not on the main server?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with jquery? Javascript and the jQuery library are client side solutions and don't get executed by the server.

Comment: My header is the same for all the pages except one in which i have to hide a logo in the header. I am calling a hide function using jquery

Answer (score 0):

try `link`:

```
<?php
    $javascript->link('jquery/jquery.min', false);
    $javascript->link('jquery/page_specific/specific_view', false);
?>
```